# Trouble deriving the Lorentz transforms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

[image]

After separately arriving at the two equations $x'=\gamma(v^2)(x-vt)$ and $t'=\phi(v^2)(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}$). Where $x'$ and $t'$ are the coordinates a moving observer ascribes to events. I had to show that the two functions $\gamma(v^2)$ and $\phi(v^2)$ are really the same. One approach that works is by saying if $x=ct$ then $\frac{x'}{t'}=c\frac{\gamma}{\phi}$. While I understand that approach, I don't see whats gone wrong here with this approach.

On a space time diagram, if v = c, both the x' and t' axis describe the same line, so surely this is a valid method.

Comment: You might want to claim $ c^2 t'^2 - x'^2 = c^2 t^2 - x^2$
and see what you can conclude about $\phi$ and $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,t)$ and $(x',t')$ assume two inertial frames of reference with relative velocity $v$ with respect to each other. In particular, your substitution $v=c$ is invalid since one cannot associate an inertial frame of reference with an observer that's co-moving with light. Your substitution assumes that the $(x,t)$ system can assume a state of rest and claim that $(x',t')$ is moving with $c$(and vice versa for $(x',t')$ claiming it's at rest and $(x,t)$ is the one moving with $c$); this violates the fundamental postulate of relativity that all inertial observers agree that light moves with $c$. There cannot be an inertial frame co-moving with light and assuming a state of rest(such a frame will claim that light is not moving with $c$ but rather at rest) cause it conflicts with the fundamental assumption of relativity.

Note what's going on in this particular step

$$\gamma(v^2)(x-ct)=\phi(v^2)(t-cx)$$

Since $x=ct$ or $x-ct=0$ and (in hindsight) $\gamma(v^2)=\phi(v^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ with $ \gamma(c^2)=\phi(c^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2/c^2}}=\infty$ Then the above equation becomes

$$\infty\cdot0=\infty\cdot0$$

Therefore one cannot conclude from this that $\gamma(c^2)=\phi(c^2)$ since this involves division by zero for both sides.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several ways to prove this.

One way is to claim that
$$ c^2 t'^2 - x'^2 = c^2 t^2 - x^2 \tag{1}$$
and see what you can conclude about $\phi(v^2)$ and $\gamma(v^2)$.

Let's begin with the calculation of the left-hand side of equation (1):
$$
\begin{align}
 &c^2 t'^2 - x'^2 \\
=& c^2 \left( \phi(v^2) \left( t - \frac{vx}{c^2} \right) \right)^2
 - \left( \gamma(v^2) (x - vt) \right)^2 \\
&\text{  I omit some steps here as an exercise for you} \\
=& \left( c^2 \phi^2(v^2) - v^2 \gamma^2(v^2) \right) t^2
 + \left( \frac{v^2}{c^2} \phi^2(v^2) - \gamma^2(v^2) \right) x^2
 + 2 \left( \gamma^2(v^2) - \phi^2(v^2) \right) vtx
\end{align}
$$

Now, by comparing this to the right-hand side of equation (1) we can easily read off:
$$
\begin{align}
c^2 \phi^2(v^2) - v^2 \psi^2(v^2) &= c^2 \\
\frac{v^2}{c^2} \phi^2(v^2) - \gamma^2(v^2) &= -1 \\
\gamma^2(v^2) - \phi^2(v^2) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

This has the solution
$$ \phi^2(v^2) = \gamma^2(v^2) = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$

For the trivial case ($v = 0$) we obviously
want the identity transformation ($x' = x, t' = t$).
That means $\gamma(0) = \phi(0) = 1$.
Therefore in the solution above only the positive root
makes sense, but not the negative one.
$$ \phi(v^2) = \gamma(v^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$